# how to add text focus in javascript using mvc 5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

**How  To add Java Script in MVC View**

I am using  mvc 5 how to use java script plz suggest us.

My model class context class are following.

plz suggest me changes for adding java script.

```
  @model MVC_Student.Models.Student

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    }

    <h2>Create</h2>


         @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Student</h4>
        <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class =     "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.M1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.M1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.M1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.M2, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.M2, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.M2, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.M3, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.M3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.M3, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Total, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Total, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Total, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
       @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Context**
    Where to add javascript in context or model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace MVC_Student.Models
{
    public class StudentContext:DbContext
    {

        public StudentContext() : base()
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Student> stud { get; set; }


    }
}

**End of Context**
```

**Model**
 In model is any thing wrong.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MVC_Student.Models
{
    public class Student
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$",ErrorMessage ="plz enter character only")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int M1 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int M2 { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int M3 { get; set; }

        [Required] 
        public int Total { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**End Of Model**

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the jquery min.js file in your cshtml page like below

And then you can use document.ready function to use $('#id').focus() function which makes focus on your required element